# Database Architecture - Keeping field with multiple values or Creating new table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to figure out the MYSQL structure best practices for fields that contain more than one value. Should you ever have a field in a table that has comma separated values or should this logic always exist in a separate table?

For Instance I have an Organization and Post table. Within this table I have the following fields:

Organization:

- ID - Integer
- Organization Name - String
- Admin - String
- Sources - String

Post:

- Post_ID - Integer
- Title - String
- Source - String (Value taken from list of "Sources")
- Organization_ID - Integer (FK)

My "Sources" field contains a predefined list of domains that can be individually selected for each "Post". Currently I have a record for an Organization that contains Sources like "wikipedia.org","google.com"

I was wondering if this is the best way to store the values or if "Sources" should be its own table and link to the Organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely sounds like you should make a many-to-many relation between organization and source.

I.e. you make a new table which has the ids from organization and source as foreign keys.